# No such file or directory: 'data_volume/finetuned_BERT_epoch_1.model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook, nlp, bert-language-model

```
for epoch in tqdm(range(1, epochs+1)):
    
    model.train()
    
    loss_train_total = 0

    progress_bar = tqdm(dataloader_train, desc='Epoch {:1d}'.format(epoch), leave=False, disable=False)
    for batch in progress_bar:

        model.zero_grad()
        
        batch = tuple(b.to(device) for b in batch)
        
        inputs = {'input_ids':      batch[0],
                  'attention_mask': batch[1],
                  'labels':         batch[2],
                 }       

        outputs = model(**inputs)
        
        loss = outputs[0]
        loss_train_total += loss.item()
        loss.backward()

        torch.nn.utils.clip_grad_norm_(model.parameters(), 1.0)

        optimizer.step()
        scheduler.step()
        
        progress_bar.set_postfix({'training_loss': '{:.3f}'.format(loss.item()/len(batch))})
         
        
    torch.save(model.state_dict(), f'data_volume/finetuned_BERT_epoch_{epoch}.model')
        
    tqdm.write(f'\nEpoch {epoch}')
    
    loss_train_avg = loss_train_total/len(dataloader_train)            
    tqdm.write(f'Training loss: {loss_train_avg}')
    
    val_loss, predictions, true_vals = evaluate(dataloader_validation)
    val_f1 = f1_score_func(predictions, true_vals)
    tqdm.write(f'Validation loss: {val_loss}')
    tqdm.write(f'F1 Score (Weighted): {val_f1}')
```

when I run the above code the below2 error is occurred, so I don't know how can I solve it, so please guide me to solve this problem.so plz tell me the correct code regarding the error.

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'data_volume/finetuned_BERT_epoch_1.model'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are saving the model in the wrong format instead of

```
 torch.save(model.state_dict(), f'data_volume/finetuned_BERT_epoch_{epoch}.model')
```

Use this

```
torch.save(model.state_dict(), f'data_volume/finetuned_BERT_epoch_model{epoch}.pth
```

you can also try different formats such as -`model.hdf5 or model.pt`

**A common PyTorch convention is to save models using either a .pt or .pth file extension.**

Answer (score 0):

**#1**

I think the dir you used to save the model is wrong, When I tried the same code like:

```
  torch.save(model.state_dict(), f'finetuned_BERT_epoch_{epoch}.model')
```

It gose good.

**#2**

instead of this:

```
torch.save(model.state_dict(), f'data_volume/finetuned_BERT_epoch_{epoch}.model')
```

I advise you to use:

```
#Change only the filepath to your own path
model.save_pretrained("/content/drive/MyDrive/Model-Output/")
```

This save the model in pytorch format, where the output folder will contains two files (`config.json` , `pytorch_model.bin` )

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a `data_volume` directory in the same place the program runs from. You could create one with `os.mkdir("data_volume")` or by going into the program folder and creating the folder there. Make sure the name is exactly right if you already have a folder